# File Input in C

Tags: c, file, file-handling

I want to input the following lines from file("input.txt") :

```
a 1,2,3,4,5,6
b 1,8
```

(i.e a character followed by a white-space and then an array separated by comma)

I have tried following code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> arr;
    FILE *file = fopen("input.txt","r");

    while(!feof(file))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        {
            fscanf(file,"%s %d,",str,&arr[i]);
        }
    }
 }
```

Let me know correct way to doing this, as it is showing garbage values

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: Btw `feof()` is not recommended as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: What is `str`? You don't check if `fopen` was successful. `arr.size()` is initially 0, so your `for` loop never executes. Please read this: [mcve].

Comment: You will want to look at [**Why is while ( !feof (file) ) always wrong?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

First of all Manisha, you are witnessing unusual code behavior because the `while` loop, which you have used, never stops. Let me tell you why in a very simple way. The stopping condition you have specified in the `while` loop, i.e, `feof()` indicates if one has tried to read past the end of file. But you can never read PAST the end of the file, which means the `while` loop would never stop.

Find an alternative way to read through the file. There are lots of other ways, one of which I have shown below:

```
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
/* note that fgets doesn't strip the terminating \n(new line character) */
...
}
if (ferror(file)) {
    /* IO failure */
} else if (feof(file)) {
    /* format error (not possible with fgets, but would be with fscanf) or end of file */
} else {
    /* format error (not possible with fgets, but would be with fscanf) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this supposed to be C or C++?  You're using a C++ data type (`std::vector`), but C I/O routines.  You haven't specified a type for `str`, either.

Assuming you mean to use C I/O routines, you could do something like this:

```
char str[SOME_LENGTH+1]; // where SOME_LENGTH is how big you expect the string to be

/**
 * Get the string at the beginning of the line; scanf should return 1
 * on a successful read.
 */
while ( scanf( "%s", str ) == 1 ) 
{
  size_t i = 0;
  /**
   * Read the sequence of integers and commas.  We consume the character
   * immediately following the integer, but don't assign it (the %*c
   * specifier).  So we'll consume the comma or newline following
   * the integer.  Since a letter isn't part of a decimal integer,
   * we'll stop scanning at the beginning of the next line.
   */
  while( scanf( "%d%*c", &arr[i++] ) == 1 )
    ; // empty loop
}
```

Note: this assumes your input is well-behaved, and that there are no spaces between the number and following comma (i.e., you don't have something like `1, 2 , 3`).

Comment: while( scanf( "%d%*c", &arr[i++] ) == 1 )
Isn't this line signifies that you're taking an integer first followed by character ?

Comment: @ManishaKeim: Yes, it reads an integer followed by a character, but the `*` in `%*c` tells `scanf` that we’re not storing that character value anywhere.  Without it, the `’,’` character would not be removed from the input stream, fouling up the next read.

Comment: but if you see in the question, I want input as character followed by comma separated array.

Comment: @ManishaKeim:  That’s what the `scanf` in the `while` loop condition is for.  It reads the the beginning of the line as a string, then reads the sequence of numbers afterwards.